# pcl::PointCloud vs. sensor_msgs::PointCloud

Tags: pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Obviously they are not the same. Which one should a developer be using?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10674/pcl::pointcloud-vs.-sensor_msgs::pointcloud/) by [ubuntuslave](https://answers.ros.org/users/631/ubuntuslave/) on ROS Answers with karma: 347 on 2011-07-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

pcl::PointCloud for "working".

sensor_msgs::PointCloud is a message for sending. You can create a pcl::PointCloud publisher that will automatically send out the right data.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-07-26**:
Documentation of how to send pcl::PointClouds natively can be found at http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl_ros